# How to find if a point is inside of a polygon using Racket

Tags: racket, polygon

I am working an a project that, given a specific latitude and longitude coordinate, outputs the neighborhood that the point resides in. I have the latitude and longitude coordinates that make up the boundaries of several neighborhoods within a city. I have to read the neighborhood data from a file, and also read the test-points from a file. I am using the Racket programming language.

So far I have been able to read the files and create a list of points for each neighborhood, and now I am stuck. I wanted to create a polygon for each neighborhood, and then have a method that checks to see if a point lies inside that polygon. However, I cannot figure out how to do that using Racket.

Can anyone help me find out how to solve if a point is inside that polygon, or perhaps a better way to go about solving the problem?

Comment: Is it a convex or a concave polygon? Or is it only a simple rectangle?

Comment: They are all concave polygons, sorry I didn't even think to mention that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I won't post any code for now because I don't want to solve the homework/assignment. However, I'll post some hints.

Look at the following picture:

[image: Some vectors]

How can we know that `C` is between the edges `OA` and `OB` and `D` is outside? It simple: we compare some angles: if the angle between `OC` and `OA` is smaller than the angle between `OB` and `OA` then C is clearly closer to `OA` than `OB` is.

Now, how do we get the angle knowing only some vectors? We can use the cosine which is monotonous: it decreases with the increasing argument. Thus, the cosine of the angle between `OC` and `OA` is greater than the cosine of the angle between `OB` and `OA` which is in turn greater that the cosine of the angle between `OD` and `OA`.

Next step is to figure out how to compute the cosine. The vector dot product helps: it's value is cosine of angle times greater than the product of operand's lengths. That is:

```
cos(OC; OA) = dotproduct(OC; OA) / (length(OA) * length(OC))
```

The dotproduct in 2D is simple:

```
dotproduct(OC; OA) = (C.x - O.x) * (A.x - O.x) + (C.x - O.x) * (A.x - O.x)
```

Combining all of the above you should have a simple test to check whether your point is in the same situation as `C` or as `D`: closer to one edge than the previous edge or not.

Now, you'll have to repeat this for every edge of the polygon and you're done. You can do this with a `fold` if the test is a predicate.

**Note**: this only works if the polygon is convex. For a concave polygon you'll need to add more tests.

**Second note**: In the figure, what will happen if `D` or `C` or both are below the `OA` line? Think about this and check if it means some more changes to the above `fold` method.

**Last note**: In a few weeks I'll post a complete code for that, assuming the assignment is over. Also, at that time I'll answer the question in the above note.

Comment: This is excellent thank you so much. I will take a closer look at this following the holiday but I understand the tests and have a plan. For reference, here is an image of the nieghborhood map to show you the types of shapes I will be working with. http://imgur.com/eZRa1fD

Comment: You'll need to split the poligons into convex ones, in order for this to work. You can use a triangle mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by collecting the segments of your polygon.
For the point P, you need determine if the horizontal ray starting from the point P intersects the side (segment).
If you count how many segments the point's horizontal ray intersects, then an odd number will be inside, and an even number will be outside.

```
  (define (point-in-polygon? point polygon)
    (odd? 
     (for/fold ([c 0]) ([seg polygon])
       (+ c (if (ray-cross-seg? point seg) 1 0))))))
```

I have a complete solution in https://github.com/StevenACoffman/lat-long-kata-racket

An alternative Ray Casting Algorithm in Racket is https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm#Racket as well as in 35 other programming languages.

A more detailed walkthrough is available: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/